# How set event on field in SQLAlchemy, that it will call only when changes concern db

Tags: python, events, sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemy, and face a problem, that I need to handle event, when one field in table is changed.
Firstly, I've tried to use code from docs:

```
@listen_for(Advert.status, 'set')
def handle_change_status(target, value, oldvalue, initiator):
    if value != oldvalue:
         # do smth
```

But this event occure any time the field is changed, even if we do not modify db. For example:

```
advert=Advert()
advert.status = 3  # event apear
```

But I need that event appear only when I commit changes:

```
db.session.add(advert)
db.session.commit()  # I need event occure here
```

I think that I can handle each 'set' event and write them in some storage, and then add event on session.commit (after_commit) and in this event handle all set events. But this approach seems not to be very neat.

May be someone has any ideas, how to solve this problem?

Comment: Could you implement a custom column? http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/custom_types.html#sqlalchemy.types.TypeDecorator

I did this one time it order to do another thing. But you could use in order to handle setting (process_bind_param)

Comment: Yes, I can. Am I right: I should override process_bind_param method?
Does this method invoke only, when data is write in db?

Comment: Yes @Igor. I think that [process_bind_param](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/custom_types.html#sqlalchemy.types.TypeDecorator.process_bind_param) is only called when the value is written to DB.

Comment: Do you want to verify is the value was changed, don't you? Well, a custom type has no access to old values. I think that [before_update](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.MapperEvents.before_update) could fit to you. You could issue another query inside before_update in order to verify if the value has changed if another query is not a problem.

Comment: Hi from 2019. Maybe `@event.listens_for(SomeClass, 'after_insert')` could help here? Version 1.3

Answer (score 1):

So, I have solve this question that way:

Firstly, I've created **init** where save init value:

`def __init__(self):
    self._init_value = self.value`

Also I've declared method, that do the same, when orm reconstruct object from db:

`@orm.reconstructor
    def init_on_load(self):
        self.__init__()`

And then I created events:

```
@event.listens_for(Model, 'after_update')
def compare_old_and_new_values(mapper, connection, target):
    if target._init_value != target.value:
        # do smth

@event.listens_for(Model, 'after_insert')
def compare_old_and_new_values(mapper, connection, target):
    if target._init_value != target.value:
        # do smth
```

`

I think this approach can have some misbehaviour, when multiple users change the same record in db, but this aproach save us from making additionals SQL queries to db.